# LXDE will not suspend when laptop lid is closed, and will die when woken up

Tags: suspend, lxde

I am not an experienced Linux user, although I have been using Ubuntu occassionally some time already. ( Since Feisty Fawn probably? ).

Now I installed Ubuntu 11.10 and it is nice ( well, after I installed LXDE, Unity sucks and I didn't really like gnome-fallback-session ),  but it has one problem:

After being suspended, when I wake my computer up, it starts up and in about 5 seconds it dies. Like a normal shutdown. Then, when I start it again, the screen stays blank, so I have to hard-turn it off - only then, when I turn it on, it works.

It is an MSI laptop, about 3-4 years old.

The second problem is:  After installing LXDE, when I close the laptop lid, it does not suspend. I can only suspend using the shutdown menu - and the waking up problem remains.

Many thanks for your time and advice guys.

Answer (score 0):

Causes of not being able to resume from suspend can be quite varied.  It may be something in a configuration file, faulty driver, or even a kernel bug.

You can try this [debugging procedure](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend).  At least it will give you more info you can report back on.

As for the LXDE problem, I have a big suspicion it is not a real issue.  LXDE doesn't load a lot of the same stuff as Unity/Gnome.  So even if in Unity you set your laptop to suspend on lid closing, that preference may not hold anymore in LXDE.  You might have to set that separately somewhere.

Before trying anything complicated, I would try seeing what happens if you load an earlier version of the kernel at the boot screen.